# No Space after `|` in Shell Scripting

Tags: shell, pipe

In certain scripts, I have seen no space between a pipe (`|`) and the next command, like so:

```
ls |echo
```

but I am used to seeing it like this:

```
ls | echo
```

Is this simply coding style, or is there a good reason to immediately follow a `|` with the command without a space?

Comment: There is no difference between the two except the visual one

Comment: @EugeneSh. Thank you, that's what I suspected. There's no chance this style circumvents any kind of bugs or security issues is there?

Comment: Can't think of any. Well, one could replace the space with some special character which looks like space, but not sure what can be gained by that.

Comment: @EugeneSh. Me neither. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's just coding style.  Of the two styles, using spaces is best for readability, and removing spaces is best for [code golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Thanks for confirming. Forgive my ignorance, but...what is `code golf` and why are no spaces good for it?

Comment: @A.Hendry, Code Golf is writing a simple program the way a golfer attempts to complete a course in the fewest strokes possible, but with Code Golf the goal is to use the fewest bytes possible.  For example, copy this harmless (and nearly unreadable) code to the command line:  [`set -- Go;M=hnny;echo -e ${1^}, $1 ${M//?/\\n${1^} Jo$M $1, $1}\\nJo$M B. ${1^}ode`](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/113381/53016)

Comment: Oh wow, interesting! Sounds like fun challenges!